# pandasのデータフレームから積み上げ棒グラフを作りたい

Tags: python, pandas, python3

pandasのデータフレームから積み上げ棒グラフを作りたいです。
classごとにグルーピングして、
x軸にclass1 , class2 , class3 を配置して
y軸にlabel を配置したいです。
その時、y軸のlabelには 0 と 1がありますのでそれぞれの件数を積み上げ棒グラフで分けたいです。
色も分けたいです。
どのようなコードを書けばよろしいでしょうか？

サンプルコードは以下になります。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#csvの生成
csv_data='''label,class,gender
1,1,1
0,1,1
0,1,0
0,1,0
0,1,0
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,0
1,1,0
0,3,1
0,3,0
0,3,0
0,3,0

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data))
```

## dfの中身を確認

```
df


label   class   gender
0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1
2   0   1   0
3   0   1   0
4   0   1   0
5   1   2   1
6   1   2   1
7   1   2   1
8   1   2   0
9   1   1   0
10  0   3   1
11  0   3   0
12  0   3   0
13  0   3   0
```

Comment: `gender`は使わないのですか?

Comment: takoikaさん genderは使いません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

方針としてはまず`class`、`label`に関しクロス集計を行い、`class`軸と`label`軸のデータフレームを作りプロットします。`plot`には積み上げグラフ用のオプション`stacked`があるので指定します。

```
pandas.crosstab(df['class'], df['label']).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]